# SharpDX - Read all past objects drawn using direct2d

Tags: directx, direct2d, sharpdx

I am new to SharpDX and using NinjaTrader 8 which uses SharpDX to render objects. Is there a way to get a list of all previously drawn objects on the RenderTarget ?

Thanks

I have tried reading documentation on SharpDX but as mentioned I am new to it. If there was a way to iterate through all objects previously drawn by sharpdx that would be great.

Comment: No, there's no way to determine what operations has been queued on the render target. This is not specifically SharpDX related, it's how Direct2D works. All drawing operations are done between BeginDraw/EndDraw methods https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nf-d2d1-id2d1rendertarget-begindraw Not sure why you would need this anyway

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @SimonMourier . I am trying to read a 3rd party indicator which rendered a point of interest in Ninjatrader 8 for me to be able to make a buy/sell decision. Appreciate the response.